# why inline element whitespace's mess with javascript/jquery?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, whitespace

to clarify the question is why would the whitespace cause issues w/ the javascript functionality?

I came across this situation today and was wondering if anyone can shed some light on things.

The js

```
button.click(function() {
    menu.show();
});
```

the html

```
<span id="button">
  <img src="btn.png" />
</span>
<ul id="menu">
    //contents here
</ul>
```

okay now here's the thing this works fine in all Chrome, FF, O, IE9 but not in IE8

now if I do this

```
<span id="button"><img src="btn.png" /></span>
<ul id="menu">
    //contents here
</ul>
```

IE8 is fixed... it also works if I structure it as

```
<span id="button"><!-- nospace
--><img src="btn.png" /><!-- nospace
--></span>
<ul id="menu">
  //contents here
</ul>
```

so I'm guessing that it is the whitespace that was messing it up. I'm just curious as to why the whitespace messes with it, or if there could be an underlying problem in my structure that these solutions just seem to fix.

any thoughts?

Comment: Do you use notepad or anything else to write the HTML?, is your file encoded as ANSI / UTF-8? it all matters. I suggest you to try it in http://jsfiddle.net/ if it still doesn't work post the fiddle and it will be easier for us to track & solve the problem.

Comment: So exactly what is messed up?

Comment: i use eclipse.. utf-8.. I'm just saying that when i structure it in a way that i don't have any type of whitespace within the span it works and when i don't it doesn't. I'm curious if all I should be conscience about is the whitespace or if there are other things that may be causing this.

Comment: I suspect something, but I need more information to confirm. Do you use php include?, if you do, try to save the pages (all the pages that you include) in UTF-8 without BOM.

Comment: @Brodie Please create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) to illustrate the problem. Or at least elaborate more concerning "DOESNTWORK". I would help, but I cannot play with it and cannot know what is the exact problem.

Comment: I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UswBC/) using the information you specified. Works for me. Feel free to edit and update it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UswBC/1/ works perefct in ie 8,9 ff & chrome.

Answer (score 0):

It treats the whitespace as a text node, which throws off the cascade. There's a bunch of whitespace bugs in old browsers which were never fixed in subsequent versions. Here are a few resources:

- [Whitespace Bugs in Browsers](http://estephenmack.com/htmlner/whitespacebugs.html)
- [IE Whitespace Bugs](http://www.cssnewbie.com/fixing-ie6-whitespace-bug/)
- [Table and Image whitespace bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993540/ie-bug-with-tds-tables-and-whitespace)