# HTML emails showing space gaps, code tested and verified, where did I go wrong?

Tags: html, html-email

I designed an e-invitation for a client. I then sliced it in PS. The image has one link in the center. That's it.

When I tested the code in DW on Safari, IE, Chrome, and FF it looked great. I even inspected the HTML file with W3C Validator and jsfiddle. However, when I insert the file in Outlook to test with email carriers such as Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail, the image appears broken into pieces; space gaps. When viewing on a mobile browser, the image looks fine. I have tried inserting recommended fixes such as `style="display:block"` or `style="vertical-align-bottom"` to no success. Did I code this wrong?

Example when inserting in Outlook: http://img39.imageshack.us/img39/7581/outlooka.jpg

Example how Safari, Chrome, IE, FF: http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/6137/35240520.jpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 6 November 2007), see www.w3.org"/>
    <title>e-invite</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<table id="Table_01" width="601" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="FFFFFF">
    <tr>
        <td width="600" height="280" colspan="3" style="font-size:0">
            <img style="display:block" src="image1.jpg" alt="" width="600" height="280" border="0" vspace="0"
                 hspace="0"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="227" height="130" rowspan="2" style="font-size:0">
            <img style="display:block" src="image2.jpg" alt="" width="227" height="130" border="0" vspace="0"
                 hspace="0"/>
        </td>
        <td width="128" height="33" style="font-size:0">
            <a href="mailto:clientemail.com">
                <img style="display:block" src="image3.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="33" border="0" vspace="0"
                     hspace="0"/>
            </a>
        </td>
        <td width="245" height="130" rowspan="2" style="font-size:0">
            <img style="display:block" src="image4.jpg" alt="" width="245" height="130" border="0" vspace="0"
                 hspace="0"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="128" height="97" style="font-size:0">
            <img style="display:block" src="image5.jpg" alt="" width="128" height="97" border="0" vspace="0"
                 hspace="0"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: why is your table 601px width and the cells only 600px and the last row only 128px?

Comment: Oh and did you tried `border-collapse: none` and `valign="top"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE bug with TD's tables and whitespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993540/ie-bug-with-tds-tables-and-whitespace)

Comment: Outlook uses its own HTML rendering engine based on Word's rather than IE's - and it's a very poor implementation. For this reason I don't suggest doing anything complicated with HTML emails. I suggest you review this resource to see if you're doing anything not supported: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338201%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: You could start by indenting properly.

Comment: @Truth, since indenting is where I should "start" .. where did I go wrong? I am here to learn, so don't assume I know as much as you or other experienced coders. In addition, if any wrong indenting was done, then it was my mistake to trust DW since it automatically displayed the code. All I had done was insert the <style="display:block;"> as mentioned in various websites in the recommended <img> location as a "fix".

Comment: @user1493551: Point taken. I will edit your question to demonstrate how proper indention should be made (I made the first comment from mobile so I couldn't do it back then)

Answer (score 0):

check width's of your table and cells,

table is 601px

top cell is 600px

<strike>lower cells are 227+128+245=594</strike> sorry my fault, calculator was set to hex

to be simple you can have only one and image and user can click anywhere...

Comment: I'll be the first to admit, I am a novice to coding. In fact, when I viewed the file in DW after PS sliced it, I just did a W3C Validator test, it found errors and "cleaned up" the code (which is what I provided via copy and paste). As for why the table is 601, I really don't know why, because the original image size is 600.

Comment: also @ neu-ray, I don't know where you got 594 from adding 227+128+245. I get 600. am i missing something?

Comment: @ oliver, where would i insert your recommendations? within the img section such as <img style="border-collapse:none" src=..."> ? or the table section

Comment: UPDATE: I believe I was able to find a way to temporarily "fix" my issue. Though it isn't what I initially wanted, what I did was went back into PS, sliced the image into width sections instead of just small mapping sections, and then rewrote the code using <div> instead of tables. I tested it out it works in Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo, but NOT Hotmail, but at this point I'll take what I have. I just used <div><img style="display:inline" src="..." width="" height="" border=""></div>. Thank you to all who provided answers. Im going to continue to research this issue, for now I have a temp fix.

Answer (score 0):

In dreamweaver you need to clear column widths and clear column heights. Even if they appear correct doing this will correct the outlook displaying problem.